# XSD - Enumeration restricted values that can be empty

Tags: xml, xsd, nullable, enumeration, restriction

I'm creating an XSD where one of the elements needs to be either empty, or a value from an enumeration:

```
<xs:element name="MyElement" nillable="true">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="A" />
      <xs:enumeration value="B" />
      <xs:enumeration value="C" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

I had hoped that by setting the `nillable` attribute to `true`, it would allow  A, B, C or an empty value:

```
<MyElement></MyElement>
```

But apparently that is not valid:

> The Enumeration constraint failed.

I've also tried to explicitly add the empty value to the enumeration:

```
<xs:enumeration value="" />
```

But no luck either:

> The Enumeration constraint failed.

Currently, I'm using a pattern instead:

```
<xs:pattern value="[ABC]{0,1}" />
```

This works, but I find this is an awful way to go for such a simple requirement. Surely there must be something I can do to allow "anything from the enumeration or empty"? Oh and don't suggest setting `minOccurs` to `0`, the tag has to be there at all times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### About using an empty value

I don't know what validator are you using but if you add `<xs:enumeration value="" />` as a child of the restriction tag then `<MyElement></MyElement>` is valid (I'm sure of that and I have already tested it in *oXygen* and a couple of online validators just in case).

So the correct way to do what you want to do it's to use an empty enumeration value or use a pattern restriction. In other words, **the two solutions you provide in your questions are correct** although your validator doesn't think so with the *enumeration* (maybe it's a bug, maybe a typo in the full Schema, I don't know).

### About nillable

`Nillable` means that in the XML instance the element can have the **nil attribute** set to *true* and then it should be empty. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="MyElement" type="xs:string" nillable="true"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

In the following example *MyElement* have the nil attribute set to true and it's empty, so it's valid against the example *XML Schema* (notice that if *MyElement* have content and *nil* set to true, then is not valid)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <MyElement ns:nil="true"></MyElement>
</root>
```

So in my opinion, using *nillable* it's not a good solution as you have to add an attribute to your XML instance. Instead of using nillable I would suggest to use enumeration as you were trying to do, and check that strange behavior of the validator.

Comment: The validator is in Visual Studio and I think it is an expansion from BizTalk.

Comment: As it turns out, it wasn't the validator but the "schema editor" in visual studio. The "empty" enumeration value was actually a space. I opened it with a regular text editor, removed the space and it validates. Thank you!